# In a URL, should spaces be encoded using %20 or +?

Tags: url, urlencode, url-encoding

In a URL, should I encode the spaces using `%20` or `+`? For example, in the following example, which one is correct?

```
www.mydomain.com?type=xbox%20360
www.mydomain.com?type=xbox+360
```

Our company is leaning to the former, but using the Java method [`URLEncoder.encode(String, String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) with `"xbox 360"` (and `"UTF-8"`) [returns the latter](http://ideone.com/5eLild).

So, what's the difference?

Comment: for the benefit of .net developers:  HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode uses '%20'   HttpUtility.UrlEncode uses '+.' source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlpathencode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @MetaByter I think it is more technically correct to phrase the question as "In a URL, should I encode the spaces using %20 or + *in the query part of a URL*?" because while the example you show includes spaces only in the query part, it might not be clear to all readers that the answer depends.  Alternatively you could word the question, "In *the specific URL examples below*, should I encode..."

Answer (score 138):

Form data (for GET or POST) is usually encoded as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`: this specifies `+` for spaces.

URLs are encoded as [RFC 1738](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738.html) which specifies `%20`.

In theory I think you should have %20 before the `?` and + after:

```
example.com/foo%20bar?foo+bar
```

Comment: Except in email links, because using +es after the ? will result in emails opening with +es still in there. So: 
`mailto:support@example.org?subject=I%20need%20help`

Answer (score 57):

According to the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/uri-spec.html) (and they are the official source on these things), a space character in the query string (and in the query string only) may be encoded as either "`%20`" or "`+`". From the section "Query strings" under "Recommendations":

> Within the query string, the plus sign is reserved as shorthand notation for a space. Therefore, real plus signs must be encoded. This method was used to make query URIs easier to pass in systems which did not allow spaces.

According to section 3.4 of [RFC2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) which is the official specification on URIs in general, the "query" component is URL-dependent:

> 3.4. Query Component
>           The query component is a string of information to be interpreted by
>           the resource.
>
> ```
>    query         = *uric
> ```
>
> Within a query component, the characters ";", "/", "?", ":", "@",
>      "&", "=", "+", ",", and "$" are reserved.

It is therefore a bug in the other software if it does not accept URLs with spaces in the query string encoded as "`+`" characters.

As for the third part of your question, one way (though slightly ugly) to fix the output from `URLEncoder.encode()` is to then [call](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) `replaceAll("\\+","%20")` on the return value.

Comment: Instead of using URLEncoder which encodes to application/x-www-form-urlencoded, use java.net.URI, which encodes in the true percent encoding.

Answer (score 8):

It *shouldn't* matter, any more than if you encoded the letter A as %41.

However, if you're dealing with a system that doesn't recognize one form, it seems like you're just going to have to give it what it expects regardless of what the "spec" says.

Answer (score 5):

You can use either - which means most people opt for "+" as it's more human readable.

Answer (score 2):

When encoding query values, either form, plus or percent-20, is valid; however, since the bandwidth of the internet isn't infinite, you should use plus, since it's two fewer bytes.

Comment: Premature optimisation .... 

Comment: upvoted cause it made me laugh

Comment: I would say a better rationale for using plus instead is that its nicer for a human to read than %20. Well for me it is anyway.