# href syntax : is it okay to have space in file name

Tags: html, syntax, anchor, href

it has always been my practice that when ever i use images i name them like
`walls_ico` , `bu_hover`

so when i give paths they go like

```
<img src="images/walls_ico.ico" />
<img src="buttons/bu_hover.png" />
```

UNTIL now when i am on a project where users upload files...

i was wondering is it okay to have spaces between file and folders name like

```
<img src="buttons/bu hover.png" />
```

Comment: **Related:** [In a URL, should spaces be encoded using %20 or +?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1211229/1497596)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The [`src`](http://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html_images.asp) attribute should contain a [valid URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Syntax). Since [space characters are not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497908/are-urls-allowed-to-have-a-space-in-them) in URLs, you have to [encode them](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_urlencode.asp).

You can write:

```
<img src="buttons/bu%20hover.png" />
```

But **not**:

```
<img src="buttons/bu+hover.png" />
```

Because, as DavidRR rightfully points out in his comment, encoding space characters as `+` is only valid in the query string portion of an URL, not in the path itself.

Comment: Basically just url encode the src, if you are working with php just use: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: I knew I should've posted my answer before checking the facts... =/ my since I said pretty much the same thing I've deleted my answer. +1 for your speed, sir! =b

Comment: **Caution:** The [W3C Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/) did not flag occurrences of `a/@href` values with spaces in XHTML Transitional files that I checked.

Comment: I do not believe that `src="buttons/bu+hover.png"` is valid. According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/497991/1497596) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1211256/1497596), encoding a space as a `+` is valid *only* in the **query string** portion of a URL. Furthermore, in tests I have just conducted, IE and Firefox both return 404 errors when I attempt to access a file where spaces in its name are (improperly) encoded as `+` characters.

Comment: But it says that this apply on for domain names. It should be ok to have spaces in src.

Answer (score 5):

Quoting HTML5 to back Frederic that spaces are not allowed:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#attr-hyperlink-href:

> The href attribute on a and area elements must have a value that is a valid URL potentially surrounded by spaces.

The definition of "valid URL" points to: http://url.spec.whatwg.org which defines URL code points https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#url-code-points:

> The URL code points are ASCII alphanumeric, "!", "$", "&", "'", "(", ")", "*", "+", ",", "-", ".", "/", ":", ";", "=", "?", "@", "_", "~", and code points in the ranges U+00A0 to U+D7FF, U+E000 to U+FDCF, U+FDF0 to U+FFFD, U+10000 to U+1FFFD, U+20000 to U+2FFFD, U+30000 to U+3FFFD, U+40000 to U+4FFFD, U+50000 to U+5FFFD, U+60000 to U+6FFFD, U+70000 to U+7FFFD, U+80000 to U+8FFFD, U+90000 to U+9FFFD, U+A0000 to U+AFFFD, U+B0000 to U+BFFFD, U+C0000 to U+CFFFD, U+D0000 to U+DFFFD, U+E1000 to U+EFFFD, U+F0000 to U+FFFFD, U+100000 to U+10FFFD.

The spec then uses the term URL code points on various parts of the parsing algorithm as:

> If c is not the EOF code point, not a URL code point, and not "%", parse error.

for the scheme, authority, relative path, query state and fragment states: so the entire URL.

Answer (score 3):

> If you are using PHP

then find out this code

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    //echo $ip."<br />";REGEXP
    //echo $name."<br />";
    echo "<table border=2px style='border-radius=20px;' align=center><tr>
    <th>Document ID</th>
    <th>Document Name Type</th>
    <th>Download Documents</th>
    </tr>";//<th>Project Document Type</th>
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $path1=$row['FOLDERNAME'] .'/'. $row['FILENAME'] .'.'. $row['DOCTYPE'];
        $path=str_replace(" ", '%20', $path1);
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['DocID'] . "</td>";
       // echo "<td>" . $row['PROJDOCTYPE'] . "</td>";Thank you. Your Apple ID is now ready for use.
        echo "<td>" . $row['DOCNAME'] . "</td>";
        echo '<td><a href=Tender/'.$path.'>'.$row['DOCNAME'].'</a></td>';
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

    mysqli_close($con);
```

Answer (score -3):

```
<body>
<img src="file:///C|/Documents and Settings/All Users/Documents/My Pictures/Sample Pictures/Water lilies.jpg"
</body>
```

spaces will be allowed only when you are working in local hosts

Comment: They're not actually allowed, what may happen to work in one case will break depending on browsers and doctypes.