# How To Make HTML Links

Tags: html

I am trying to make an href button that when clicked changes the image on my website page to another image. How precisely can I do this?

I am trying to use the following code to point "Page 2" to `page 2.html` doc in my files as to change the image. The file cannot be found however.

```
<a href=“<a href=“page 2.html”> Page 2</a>
```

I do apologize if I am vague/if this question has been answered in past--Stack has been immensely helpful for answering my questions in past but I am just very confused as to how to solve this.

Thank you

Comment: I think this should answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172579/html-href-syntax-is-it-okay-to-have-space-in-file-name

Answer (score 1):

correct syntax:

```
<a href="file" >link to be seen on page </a>
```

so for you:

```
<a href="page2.html"> Page 2</a>
```

If the file has a space in it, you should put a `%20` where the space is:

```
href="page%202.html
```

Comment: I'm afraid that that the page 2.html file still cannot be found when I click on it. Is this a problem because it cannot find page 2.html within the folder on my desktop? I am using a Mac--I'm not sure if that means I have to be more specific as to local file location. Thanks.

Comment: it should work if the files are both in the same folder. to troubleshoot you might want to remove the space, just to remove a possible problem

Answer (score 0):

`page 2.html` shouldn't contain any spaces. Consider this: `<a href="page2.html">Page 2</a>`

Answer (score 0):

If this is not still working `<a href="page2.html">page 2</a>` , try to input the whole file path. eg. `<a href="C:\Users\Me\Desktop\folder\page2.html">page 2</a>` . You may also refer 
 [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp)