# I can click play, but no video plays

Tags: html, video

I have this video:

```
<video src='videos/StressedOut.mp4' class='prize_video' controls></video>
```

I've *checked*, the URL is working. `.prize_video` doesn't affect the function of the video, only the style:

```
.prize_video {
  width: 800px;
  height: 480px;
  position: relative;
  left: 22px;
}
```

**I can click play, but the video won't start...**

Comment: You have a space in *"Stressed Out.mp4"*. Is that really allowed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172579/html-href-syntax-is-it-okay-to-have-space-in-file-name

Comment: Thanks, I got rid of the space, but the problem still continues. When I go into view source, I can open the url of the video. Why is this happening?

Comment: and you don't have a screen telling that no supported format were found? Also, what does the network panel of your developer tools says? Also, the space in `src` should work on most platforms and browsers.