# I can start my video but can't play it

Tags: html, video

I have this video:

```
<video src='videos/StressedOut.mp4' class='prize_video' controls></video>
```

I've *checked*, the URL is working. `.prize_video` doesn't affect the function of the video, only the style:

```
.prize_video {
  width: 800px;
  height: 480px;
  position: relative;
  left: 22px;
}
```

**I can click play, but the video won't start...**

Comment: Please don't ask [same questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36993990/i-can-click-play-but-no-video-plays) multiple times, and why multiple accounts ? Instead, edit the first one, it will go back at top of streams. Now, you didn't answered to the comments that were posted on yesterday's one :

Comment: Could you share the video file as well?

Comment: @JeffPuckettII I'm not using YouTube...

Answer (score 0):

check the direct link of the video file in the web browser, could be the file permissions.

or could be an unsupported format such as HEVC

Comment: If it was one of these two possibilities, then I guess, *"I've checked, the URL is working"* wouldn't be part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @David please check the video file permissions since I ran the html and css [here](https://jsfiddle.net/w0aq1883/1/) with different video and it works fine.

HTML:

```
<video src='http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4' class='prize_video' controls></video>
```

CSS:

```
.prize_video {
  width: 800px;
  height: 480px;
  position: relative;
  left: 22px;
}
```

Also verify following:

- Correct file name
- File format(any variation of mp4?)
- Relative file location

P.S. It can be something very trivial causing problem too.

Comment: what make's this an answer?

Comment: Not exactly a solution rather evidence that the html/css snippet is working.

Answer (score 0):

try adding the mime type as an attribute in the video tag, to select the correct video codec by the web browser.

```
<video src='videos/StressedOut.mp4' type="video/mp4" class='prize_video' controls></video>
```