# Include link to local html file in DataTable in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I want to include a link to a local html file, which lives inside the www directory of my shiny app, inside a column in data.table. On click a new tab should open showing the html file.
I've found solutions for linking to internet pages, but how do I adjust this, so that Shiny finds the local files, when rendered in a browser?

This is my code

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)

link <- "www/my_html.html"
link <- paste0("<a href='", link,"' target='_blank'>", link,"</a>")  # works fine for global url, but not for local file
df <- data.frame(a = 10.5, b = 48, link = link)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput('table1')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table1 <- DT::renderDataTable({df}, escape = -3)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could try running your app using a shiny folder. Make sure your my_html.html file is located in a `www` folder in your shiny folder.

ui.R

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)

fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput('table1')
)
```

server.R

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)

df <- data.frame(a = 10.5, b = 48, link = "<a href='my_html.html' target='blank' >MyFile</a>")

function(input, output) {
  output$table1 <- DT::renderDataTable({df}, escape = FALSE)
}
```

Comment: Nice, it works with your code. It would also work with escape = 3 (I got this the wrong way round). But the code fails when I have an html file, which is called "my html" with an empty space in between. What do I have to change, so that this works?

Comment: this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172579/html-href-syntax-is-it-okay-to-have-space-in-file-name might help you :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem with your code is that you are specifying the address of your html file as `link <- "www/my_html.html"`. You should drop out the `www/`.

It is true that **inside your app directory you must have a www directory, and your html files should be inside this www directory.** But to properly address your files you should think as if your working directory was already inside the www/ directory.

If you have your shinny app in a single `app.R` file or a combination of `ui.R + server.R` doesn't matter, both ways work.

The other detail is in the `escape` parameter of the `renderDataTable()` function. It should not be equal to -3, use instead: `DT::renderDataTable({df}, escape = FALSE)`

So the final code would look like this (supposing you have two html files):

```
library(shiny)

link <- c("my_html_1.html", "my_html_2.html")
link <- sprintf('<a href="%s" target="_blank">click_here</a>', link)

df <- data.frame(name = c("1st_file", "2nd_file"), 
    value = c(10.5, 48), 
    link = link)

ui <- fluidPage(
  dataTableOutput('table1')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table1 <- renderDataTable({df}, escape = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```