# Linking to a local .html file from ShinyR

Tags: shiny, href

My question is the same as this:

[Include link to local html file in DataTable in Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41784631/include-link-to-local-html-file-in-datatable-in-shiny?rq=1)

however, the link generated is not working and I can't work out why!

I have followed the steps suggested. However, when I click on the hyperlink, the page displays "Not Found". I have inspected the link that is generated:

http://xxx.x.x.x:xxxx/MY_HTML.html

it generates a link to an IP address and the file name, not the local file path (C:/users/.....MY_HTML.html).

I have a ui.R file and a server.R file saved in a folder, I have tried putting MT_HTML.html in the same folder or in a subfolder "www" however neither helps.

Here is an example of the output in the server.R file:

```
output$datatable <- DT::renderDataTable({
data <- data %>%
  mutate(Group.Name=paste0("<a href='MY_HTML.html', target='_blank'>",MY_HTML,"</a>"))
DT::datatable(data=data,
              rownames=F,escape=F))}
```

Can anyone help? Thanks!