# cannot pass argument containing space to vbs function

Tags: html, windows, vbscript

```
    function readFromRegistry (strRegistryKey, strDefault)
    Dim WSHShell, value
     On Error Resume Next
    Set WSHShell = CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
    value = WSHShell.RegRead (strRegistryKey)
    if err.number <> 0 then
        readFromRegistry= strDefault
    else
        readFromRegistry=value
    end if    
    set WSHShell = nothing
   end function

function OpenWithChrome(sPage)
    Dim strChrome
    Dim WShellChrome  
    strChrome = readFromRegistry ( "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\chrome.exe\Path", "") 
    if (strChrome = "") then
        strChrome = "chrome.exe"
    else
        strChrome = strChrome & "\chrome.exe"
    end if
    Set WShellChrome = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    strChrome = """" & strChrome & """" & " " & sPage
    WShellChrome.Run strChrome, 1, false
  end function  
    OpenWithChrome "auto slides.html"
```

At last line i'm calling function OpenWithChrome with argument containing spaces. But it unable to open that file in my browser.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to encode your space so Chrome can understand it.  Change that line to:

```
OpenWithChrome "auto%20slides.html"
```

More information on encoding html files that use spaces can be found here:

[HTML: href syntax : is it okay to have space in file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172579/html-href-syntax-is-it-okay-to-have-space-in-file-name)