# bootstrap4 carousel image squished

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am using bootstrap4 and my image in the carousel is squished. It was working fine before but when i updated the CDN the carousel changed too. There might not be anything different in the code between the two versions as when i updated to the new carousel code that matched the new CDN, the same issue occured.

```
   <!--carousel-->
  <div class="container-fluid"> <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" 
class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
<li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
<li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
<li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
<div class="carousel-item active">
  <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="images/trend board - 1.jpg" alt="First slide">
</div>
<div class="carousel-item">
  <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="images/trend board - 2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
</div>
<div class="carousel-item">
  <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="images/trend board - 3.jpg" alt="Third slide">
</div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
<span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
<span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
</div>


<!--CDN-->
<!--bootstrap 4 beta-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: Are you trying to use beta or alpha.6? You comment says beta, but CDN is pointing to alpha.6

Answer (score 0):

My guess is it's an issue with the your `src` attributes on your `img` tags. These have to be valid URLs, and since they have spaces, those attributes would not be considered valid. Here's a link to another [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172579/html-href-syntax-is-it-okay-to-have-space-in-file-name) that address that particular issue.

I put together a [codeply project](https://www.codeply.com/go/nuty9JgATj) with the carousel from bootstrap 4 beta. When you put valid URLs in the `src` attributes, everything works as expected.