# Background image not working although path is correct

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to clone a website in my local environment. For some reason, background image doesn't show even though the path is correct as shown in the jpg below.

The photo is in the same folder as index.html and style.css. The css is below:

```
.wallpaper {
    background-image:url('jobbatical-1-wallpaper.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
}

.navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: green;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
}

.navbar a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: blue;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

[image: background img path]

Comment: or replace the spaces with %20 also make sure you have set a height of 100% for html and body as it doesn't look like your div has any height

Comment: The img is in the same folder as index.html. I've changed the name already, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Then problem is your html/css, wallpaper is set to height:100%...of what?

Comment: @sinisake what do u mean? And what do you suggest I do?

Comment: what is with the amount of downvotes lol... okay I'm reading up on Holy grail layout

Comment: Well, downvoters are always ready, lol....however, easy fix would be to set 100% height to parent element, which is body, in this case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that 100% height is useless if the parent has no height.

What do height do you want the image to have? 100% of the viewport or just fill the page?

(100% of the viewport would mean that you have to scroll to see the full picture because of your navbar)

Here is the code of the image should copy the height of the viewport:
(EDIT: maybe you should set the height of the image to `100vh` instead of bodys height)

```css
html,
body
{
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

.navbar
{
  background-color:green;
  height:50px;
}
.image
{
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(black,gray);
}
```

```html
  <div class="navbar"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
```

Here is the code if you want to fill the parent (using flex):

```css
body
{
  margin: 0px;
}
.viewport
{
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}
.navbar
{
  background-color: green;
  height: 50px;
}
.image
{
  background-image: linear-gradient(black,gray);
  flex-grow: 1;/*This will make the image to fill the parents space*/
}
```

```html
<div class="viewport">
  <div class="navbar"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your div has no height. You can tell because you can see the position of the paragraph under it.

Since it has no height, there are no pixels to display the background image on.

You need to give it a height.

You have tried giving it `height: 100%` but a percentage height means `height: auto` (i.e. the height of the content, of which you have none) when the parent element's height is `auto` (which the `body` element is by default).

If you want to make a div take up the remaining vertical space after other elements have been accounted for, look at *flexbox* for layout. The [Holy Grail layout](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/holy-grail/) is a fairly extreme example of that.

Answer (score -1):

Space characters aren't allowed in url's.
So you either don't use spaces or [encode](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) it when calling it with `%20` instead of the space.
I personally use - or _ instead.

[Stackoverflow: "href syntax : is it okay to have space in file name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172579/href-syntax-is-it-okay-to-have-space-in-file-name)

Comment: The browser clearly doesn't have any problems with the URL because it is rendering the preview image in the developer tools in the screenshot.