# Can't get the output right (display an image from a MYSQL databse in PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, image

I have created a simple display website for my Kodi database. The data for this site comes from a MySQL database.

When I use this code: (to display a cover from a Album)

```
<td><?php echo '<img src='.$row['url']," width='150' height='175' />"; ?>
```

I'll get an result of:

```
<img src="smb://10.0.0.61/Media/Muziek/Albums/Bryan" adams="" mtv="" unplugged="" [live]="" folder.jpg="" width="150" height="175">
```

As you can see the result has been hacked up and the retrieval is not possible. I was wondering what additional code is needed to retrieve the complete path and display the image. The correct path is:

```
smb://10.0.0.61/Media/Muziek/Albums/Bryan Adams/MTV Unplugged [Live]/Folder.jpg
```

Comment: You did not add open `"` at this part of code `img src='`. Try: `<td><?php echo '<img src="'.$row['url']," width='150' height='175' />"; ?>`

Comment: I would suggest doing echos in this way (much clearer): <td><img src="<?= $row['url'] ?>" width="150" height="175" /> There is no need to add static html to printed variable, when this can stay in your html. Much easier to debug :)

Answer (score 1):

Check your syntax here, change this..

```
<td><?php echo '<img src='.$row['url']," width='150' height='175' />"; ?>
```

To this..

```
<td><?php echo '<img src="'.$row['url'].'" width="150" height="175" />'; ?> </td>
```

Also, try removing the spaces from folder names, change it for a `-` or a `_` instead. If you don't want to change the folder names, you can also encode them. Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4172592/9039888) for more info

Comment: I saw that the output is now correct. The image however is not there....

Comment: Make sure the path and file format are correct, have you only changed the syntax or did you also deal with the spaces?

Comment: I have tried it with this additional code:

<?php preg_match('/preview="([^"]+)"/', $row['c08'], $matches); ?>

Also with:

'/preview="([^"]+)"/'

but no luck as off yet

Comment: Since you are using php, you can just use the enconde funtcion (http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) instead of regex.. Make sure the path is correct by right clicking the image on your web page (or where it was supposed to be) and then click "inspect element"

Comment: Did that and got the next result:

<img src="smb://10.0.0.61/Media/Muziek/Albums/Bryan Adams/MTV Unplugged [Live]/Folder.jpg" width="150" height="175">

Which is ok, but still no picture. I understand it's because of a space in it, but with other pages on the same site (Movie or Serie covers) it works and displays the image (That code returned in: <img src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/iBlfxlw8qwtUS0R8YjIU7JtM6LM.jpg" style="\&quot;width:150px;height:175px;\&quot;">) And Yes, the first is local on a server, the second online from IMDB

Comment: I have looked for a album without spaces in name, or album name and found one. For this album no image is diplayed. the path is:

<img src="smb://10.0.0.61/Media/Muziek/Albums/Enya/Amarantine/Folder.jpg" width="150" height="175">

When I inspect the code behind it, it only tells me the pricture couldn;t be loaded. why? (*not known)