# My first image doesn't show in my slideshow for website

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

I have searched high and low for a solution to my problem - I am new to coding and have tried to insert a slideshow into my website using javascript... Everything works fine just the first image does not show for whatever reason? I assume the answer is to do with something in my css file but I could be wrong? When I click on the dots at the bottom of my page the slideshow works and images fire up, it's just getting the first image to show that is the problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```js
    var slideIndex = 1;
    showSlides(slideIndex);

    // Next/previous controls
    function plusSlides(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }

    // Thumbnail image controls
    function currentSlide(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }

    function showSlides(n) {
      var i;
      var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
      var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
      if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1;} 
      if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length;}
      for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none"; 
      }
      for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
      }
      slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
      dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    }
```

```css
    * {box-sizing:border-box}

    /* Slideshow container */
    .slideshow-container {
      max-width: 1000px;
      position: relative;
      margin: auto;
       }

    /* Hide the images by default */



    .mySlides {
        display:none;
    }



    /* Next & previous buttons */
    .prev, .next {
      cursor: pointer;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      width: auto;
      margin-top: -22px;
      padding: 16px;
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 18px;
      transition: 0.6s ease;
      border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
      }

    /* Position the "next button" to the right */
    .next {
     right: 0;
     border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
     }

     /* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-
    through */
    .prev:hover, .next:hover {
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    }

    /* Caption text */
    .text {
      color: #f2f2f2;
      font-size: 15px;
      padding: 8px 12px;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 8px;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
    }

    /* Number text (1/3 etc) */
    .numbertext {
      color: #f2f2f2;
      font-size: 12px;
      padding: 8px 12px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
    }

    /* The dots/bullets/indicators */
    .dot {
      cursor:pointer;
      height: 15px;
      width: 15px;
      margin: 0 2px;
      background-color: #bbb;
      border-radius: 50%;
      display: inline-block;
      transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
    }

    .active, .dot:hover {
      background-color: #717171;
    }

    /* Fading animation */
    .fade {
      -webkit-animation-name: fade;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
      animation-name: fade;
      animation-duration: 1.5s;

    }



        @-webkit-keyframes fade {
          from {opacity: .4} 
          to {opacity: 1}
        }

        @keyframes fade {
          from {opacity: .4} 
          to {opacity: 1}
        }
```

```html
    <html>
     <head>
  
      <script src="slideshow-container.js"></script>
      <link href="css/styles.css" "slider.css" rel="stylesheet" 
    type="text/css" media="screen" >
       <link href="css/slideshow-container.css" rel="stylesheet" 
    type="text/css">
     </head>

    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
  
      <div id="logo">
  
     <li>
        <div id="links">
          <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Welcome </a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery.html">Treatments</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        
         </ul>
       
  
  
      </div> 
        <a href="maintest.html"><img src= "Images/untitled folder/My 
    Choice Logo.jpg" width="350" class="fade">
      
            </a></li>
      </div>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
 
 
     <!-- Slideshow container -->
    <div class="slideshow-container">

      <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
      <div id="slide1" class="mySlides fade">
   
        <img src="Images/untitled folder/My Choice Logo.jpg" 
    style="width:100%">
 
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">
    
        <img src="Images/untitled folder/Natural-Dog-Law-2-To-dojhgs,-energy-
    is-everything.jpg" style="width:100%">
   
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">
   
        <img src= "Images/untitled folder/Treatment room.jpg" 
    style="width:100%">
   
      </div>

      <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
    <br>

    <!-- The dots/circles -->
    <div style="text-align:center">
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
    </div>
```

Comment: You need to post the html also as its hard to ensure you have the correct structure which i suspect is the problem.

Comment: *That text is definitely italic.*

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, wasn't expecting a response! I've edited the html code into my original question... And ideas? It's basically copy and pasted from another source, I've edited it slightly to suit my needs but made no alterations to the arrangement or to anything that would effect the dynamics of how it should work. It works fine on its own in the website example just the first image is acting shy on my web page

Comment: Some of those image sources (filenames) have spaces in them, which may be causing problems. See here on how to fix that:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172579/href-syntax-is-it-okay-to-have-space-in-file-name
The second image source in the series has a comma also, which is definitely a problem. Also in the pasted code, that DIV wrapper may be unclosed.

Comment: Hi I've made the changes you suggested and I've only pasted the code up to the slideshow part and rechecked that all divs are closed and that the images are working fine? It's just the first image that doesn't seem to work when the page loads up initially, if I scroll through the banner the will appear once the image reaches image one and the slideshow will work as it should do. Very frustrating for me as it took me a good few hours to work out how to link the javascript to the css etc

Answer (score 4):

I've managed to fix this. Not sure how good of a fix this is but a bit of playing about with the other functions of css and my basic understanding of html and css I created a new  for slide one only and closed it the commanded in css that the image was show as a block... because it was in its own  it hasn't placed it on top of the other images as it would normally

new html

```
     <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
   <div id="slide1" class="mySlides fade" >

    <img src="Images/untitled folder/MyChoiceLogo.jpg" 
style="width:100%">

  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">

    <img src="Images/untitled folder/Natural-Dog-Law-2-To-dojhgs-
energy-is-everything.jpg" style="width:100%">

  </div>
```

new css (added)

```
.mySlides {


    display:none;
}

#slide1 {display:block}
```

Thanks for the people who looked and this and I hope my solution doesn't cause any problems? Hopefully this can help anyone who is struggling like I did and I am open to any other ideas on how to fix :) Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Call the function

`currentSlide(1);`

in your js which will make the first slide visible on page load.