# why i can't link image and CSS and favicon in PHP

Tags: php, html, css

my PHP file can't link CSS or image or favicon in the HTML part I have used this code so many times in HTML not PHP and it fully works I don't know what is the problem in my code
I

```html
<link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="GoFixWare logo.ico"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap">
<img class="d-block mx-auto mb-4" src="GoFixWare-logos_transparent.png" alt="" width="100" height="100">
<img src="img_bg-min.jpg" class="d-block mx-lg-auto img-fluid" alt="Bootstrap Themes" width="700" height="500"
            loading="lazy">
```

am using xampp

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap">
<link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="GoFixWare logo.ico">
```

Comment: relative path? rewrite in server? I suspect you’re not in document root so it’s looking in a subdirectory

Comment: you have space in href.
more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172579/href-syntax-is-it-okay-to-have-space-in-file-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="GoFixWarelogo.ico">
```

rename your icon, more here [href syntax : is it okay to have space in file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172579/href-syntax-is-it-okay-to-have-space-in-file-name)

Answer (score 0):

Try using src in place of href in link tag

Comment: Are your css files in same folder or you have created a css folder with in parent folder

Comment: Your upper code work fine and the second code does not if I am not right