# I uploaded my html, css and image files on Github. When I view the website on my Github page, the images do not show as they do locally, only as icons

Tags: html, image, github

```
<div class="image1">
   <img src="../images/Igbo Calendar.png">
</div>
<div class="image2">
   <img src="../images/RCCG directory.png">
</div>
<div class="image3">
   <img src="../images/Igbostudy quiz .png">
</div>
```

I uploaded my html, css and image files on Github. When I view the website on my Github page, the images do not show as they do locally, only as icons

I removed the dots and the forward slash before the 'images' to see if it helped, it did not. I searched similar questions here on Stackoverflow but the suggestions I applied did not solve the problem.

github page: https://ijeoma7.github.io/website-two/

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hi this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4172592/8602886, space characters are not allowed in URLs

Comment: It appears that the images are not located in the `images` subfolder, but in the same folder; This image URL works for me `https://ijeoma7.github.io/website-two/Igbo%20Calendar.png`

Answer (score 0):

you upload images directly you not upload images
so this "../images/Igbo Calendar.png" to "Igbo Calendar.png"

[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znZgs.png)

```
  <div class="image1">
   <img src="Igbo-calendar.png">
  </div>
  <div class="image2">
   <img src="RCCG-directory.png">
  </div>
  <div class="image3">
   <img src="Igbostudy-quiz.png">
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I would avoid using spaces in file names when it comes to the web--use dash (-) or underscores (_) if you want to separate words in file names. For example, try changing your html code and file names to the following:

```
<div class="image1">
   <img src="../images/Igbo-calendar.png">
</div>
<div class="image2">
   <img src="../images/RCCG-directory.png">
</div>
<div class="image3">
   <img src="../images/Igbostudy-quiz.png">
</div>
```

Second, I would double check that the image relative paths and filenames you have specified is correct in the uploaded site. (Single ./ (or no prefix) represents the directory you are in, ../ represents the parent directory, ../../ represents the gradparent directory, and so on.)

Comment: thanks everyone that answered