# Decode url '+' to '%20' from Form GET query parameters

Tags: javascript, url, urlencode, url-encoding

I use *meta-refresh* tag in my html page. The html page has a form. When this page is auto-refreshed, all form parameters are appended to url as HTTP GET parameter.

**Problem:** 
All space characters i.e '%20' is converted to '+' automatically. But my FORM Query params may themselves have '+' characters in their content. So

- How do I stop spaces replaced by '+' and go back to encoding space with '%20'?

OR

- How do I correctly encode and decode Form params to properly differentiate between space-representing '+' and literal parameter '+' ?

---

**E.G.**

properTitle = "This is example for correctly decoding HTTP Form parameters space replaced with '+'"
*encodeURIComponent(properTitle)* : 
This%20is%20example%20for%20correctly%20decoding%20HTTP%20Form%20parameters%20space%20replaced%20with%20'%2B'

*escape(properTitle)* : This%20is%20example%20for%20correctly%20decoding%20HTTP%20Form%20parameters%20space%20replaced%20with%20%27+%27

**After meta-refresh**
skewedTitle = "This+is+example+for+correctly+decoding+HTTP+Form+parameters+space+replaced+with '+'"

*decodeURIComponent(skewedTitle)* : This+is+example+for+correctly+decoding+HTTP+Form+parameters+space+replaced+with+'+

*escape(skewedTitle)* :  This+is+example+for+correctly+decoding+HTTP+Form+parameters+space+replaced+with+%27%252B%27

**P.S:** I have already referenced following similar questions but no help.

[When to encode space to plus (+) or %20?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678551/when-to-encode-space-to-plus-or-20)

[In a URL, should spaces be encoded using %20 or +?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211229/in-a-url-should-spaces-be-encoded-using-20-or)

**EDIT 1:**
Thanks to @Bergi, I have solved my problem by manually encoding '+' character to '%2b' before refresh itself. After meta-refresh '%20' is converted to '+' which is different from '%2b'. Shouldn't there be a proper method to take care of such encoding and decoding ?

Comment: It sounds like your real problem is that the original URL contains `+` characters that should be encoded to `%2B`. You need to address that.

Comment: My real problem is space being encoded as '+' which then confuses me if original param too contains '+' in its native form. How do i stop url space being encoded as '+' ?

Comment: `+` is a perfectly acceptable way of encoding a space in a URL. If the original param contains literal `+` that means `+` instead of a space, then the original param was encoded incorrectly.

Comment: How should below param value look when encoded correctly ?
"This contains + "

Comment: @Sourabh: Either `This%20contains%20%2B%20` or `This+contains+%2B+`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "*all form parameters are appended to url as HTTP GET parameter*". Is the form auto-submitted or what? Are you doing this by JavaScript? If yes, please show the code of that.

Comment: Hi @ Bergi, It seems in html, a form params are appended as GET params when refreshed. Pls refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678551/when-to-encode-space-to-plus-or-20#comment2698216_2678602

Answer (score 0):

Use `decodeURIComponent()` to decode the URL.

**EDIT**

```
var str = "Happy%20Day";
```

Then Do

```
str = str.replace("%20", " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on the following, might help you-

> `HttpUtility.UrlEncode("Stack Overflow") --> "Stack+Overflow"`
>   `Uri.EscapeUriString("Stack Overflow") --> "Stack%20Overflow"`
>   `Uri.EscapeDataString("Stack +  Overflow") --> Also encodes "+" to "%2b" ---->Stack%20%2B%20%20Overflow`

Comment: Hi Rajat_RJT, Uri.EscapeDataString() seems to be C# specific. Any equivalent method from JS/ JQuery stable ?

Comment: Hey Sourabh, i basically work with C# but "HttpUtility.UrlDecode" may help you