# uri.getQueryParameters() method converting "+" Character with space

Tags: java, javax.ws.rs

Problem is like uri.getQueryParameters()  method is converting Character(+) into space which I am trying to avoid. 
Below is the uri before

```
"http://localhost:8081/service/linear/test/?id=test+QYY"
```

after
`uri.getQueryParameters()` will remove the + and it will replace with space 
so the id now **doesn't** contains the **+** instead it **contains** the **space** as below

```
"http://localhost:8081/service/linear/test/?id=test QYY"
```

Notes - 
uri is a object of [UriInfo](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html) which is defined by package javax.ws.rs.core

Comment: here is an answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29824160/why-doesnt-uriinfo-getqueryparameters-decode

Comment: but this is for java 7 , i am looking for java 6

Comment: How do i replace the + with the decoded the string ?

Comment: So for my case i need to decode something as below

Answer (score 4):

I know is a little late, but I found out in the same situation and I realized that the getQueryParameters is working right instead of getQueryParameter.
In my case the char "+" in the Uri with the getQueryParameter let an empty space, and with the getQueryParameters works fine.