# Custom URI scheme removes spaces before the "hashtag sign" (#)

Tags: windows, uri, url-scheme

i'm writing custom URI scheme, following this article:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx

my handler looks like this:
myScheme://firstItem/SecondItem

the thing is, after the first slash, if i write the "#" with spaces, all spaces are removed.

example:

```
myScheme://first/second #third
```

is interpreted as:

```
myScheme://first/second#third
```

in my application.

in addition, if it's the first parameter before the slash, a slash is added:

```
myScheme://first #second
```

is interpreted as:

```
myScheme://first /#second
```

in my application.

Can anyone can explain this behavior?

== EDIT ==

mailto: protocol is the only one who is implemented in similar way, and is working well.
onenote, winamp, etc... can't handle those cases.

anyone knows why?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you use percent-encoded spaces, e.g,.

- [In a URL, should spaces be encoded using %20 or +?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211229/in-a-url-should-spaces-be-encoded-using-20-or)
- [URL encoding the space character: + or %20?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634271/url-encoding-the-space-character-or-20)

The page *[Registering an Application to a URI Scheme](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)* lists more than one problem with spaces in a URI:

> By adding the above settings to the registry, navigating to URIs such as `alert:Hello%20World` would cause an attempt to launch `alert.exe` with the complete URI on the command line. Internet Explorer percent-decodes the URI, but the Windows Run... command does not. If a URI contains percent-encoded spaces, it may be split across more than one argument on the command line.

The "split" corresponds to your second part of the question.  But later, it comments

> When ShellExecute executes the pluggable protocol handler with a stringon the command line, any non-encoded spaces, quotes, and backslashes in the URI will be interpreted as part of the command line. This means that if you use C/C++'s argc and argv to determine the arguments passed to your application, the string may be broken across multiple parameters. To mitigate this issue:

The last part is the recommendation:

> ***Avoid*** spaces, quotes, or backslashes in your URI

because one part of the system will rely upon percent-encoding while the other is broken by it.

Comment: i dont mind if the string will be broken into several parameters, i can't tell the end user to encode the special characters.
i saw that mailto: doesn't have this issue, nor custom developed protocol handler.
isn't there any way that my application will just receive what i've sent?

Comment: Apparently not: the applications get a filtered/translated version of what you send.

Comment: So i wonder how mailto overcame this problem.. as it seems they don't have this issue (the sender receives the exact string that is sent)