# how to implement protocols like mailto: or file:?

Tags: uri, protocol-handler

this relates to this question:

[Custom URI scheme removes spaces before the "hashtag sign" (#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33545536/custom-uri-scheme-removes-spaces-before-the-star-sign)

I have a custom application, which i require to register to a protocol and open it via arguments.

i've implemented it using: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx

but the problem is that windows truncates some of my arguments (removes spaces in several occasions).

for example,

```
myScheme://first/second #third
```

turns into

```
myScheme://first/second#third
```

in my app.

i saw that it doesn't happen in "mailto" or "file" protocol handlers.
i'm not sure what's the best way to address this issue then.

i need a simple sample of doing so,
i tried doing an implementation using "pluggable protocol handler" but i'm not sure this is what i need, as it just opens internet explorer with my URL. 
mailto/file are using custom DLL that implements it, and thats what i aim for.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, it is unclear what you ask. I suggest that instead of writing _how you might_ do something you simply write _what it is_ you want to do. That would enable us to make suggestions.

Comment: @arkascha i'll update my post

Comment: Should space characters (' ') in URIs not be encoded as '%20', like it is done in URLs?