# <a tag in html is not working with <div class="subnav">

Tags: html

I'm writing a code for my website in html.when I use < a tag as below its not working (bad).

```
<div id="column">
  <div class="subnav">


      <li><a href="Introduction To File.html">Introduction To File</a></li>


          <li><a href="File Access Mode.html">File Access Mode</a></li>
          <li><a href="Error in opening file.html">Error Handling</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Closing File</a></li>
          <li><a href="End of file.html">End of File</a></li>
          <li><a href="fcloseall() vs exit().html">fcloseall() vs exit()</a></li>
          <li><a href="getchar() and putchar().html">getchar() and putchar()</a></li>
          <li><a href="getc() and putc().html">getc() and putc()</a></li>
          <li><a href="fputc() and fgetc().html">fputc() and fgetc()</a></li>
          <li><a href="fgets.html">fgets()</a></li>

  </div>
</div>
```

NOTE: when I click on **Introduction To File** i am not sent to **Introduction To File.html** page(bad) but, when i insert

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

then i m sent to **Introduction To File.html**  page and the  problem is after adding "clear"  some unwanted space seems to be added which is bad.

Please help to find where i went wrong?

Comment: Your <li>'s are not in a <ul> or <ol>

Comment: Also note that the URLs you code inside you anchors (`<a>` tags) are  formally invalid if they contain characters like spaces. you have to `urlencode()` those links to be valid. Currently it is up to the browser what it makes out of those invalid notations.

Comment: i tired adding it too but still no luck

Comment: Weird, in my case, it is working great, i copied your code, putted it into jsfiddle and.. working? link there => https://jsfiddle.net/kwnrwrwj/

Comment: @PetrCihlar It worked for me too.. just by copy pasting his code

Comment: @Reddy yeah... So where is his problem (without bad code and so..)... ? :-D

Comment: @PetrCihlar No idea, it must be something else which he has not shown here

Comment: @Reddy please check this link http://codemedad.com/c/File/Close%20a%20file.html here the link on left is not working i have used the above code

Comment: @rick I gave my answer. Let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is invalid. `<li>` elements cannot be child elements of `<div>`. They must be enclosed within an `<ul>`

Also, [you need to encode the spaces in your URL to %20.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211229/in-a-url-should-spaces-be-encoded-using-20-or) That is the character encoding for spaces. Otherwise it will be misinterpreted as you have found.

[URL Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the link you provided in the comment, The issue is simple. You have a `div` with id `container` and this div is overlaying on your left menu's. So its like a invisible wrapper above the left menu. So you will never be able to click the anchor tags. Place this CSS rule in your code and it must work

Here  you already have this

```
  #header, #topbar, #topnav, #breadcrumb, #container, #footer, #copyright {
    position: initial;
    margin: 0 auto 0;
    display: block;
    width: 96%;
  }
```

Add this CSS rule to overwrite the above `position:relative` rule.

```
 #container {
     position: initial; 
    }
```

with the above code the overlapping is removed and you are able to click the links.

---

*For a quick check, paste this in your browser console and you can see the links are clickable.*

```
$('#container').css('position','initial');
```