# A property has a space and Href is ignorning everything after it

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, href, azure-storage

I can download an uploaded file to Azure using a direct link, seemed the quickest and easiest way to do it. By no means the safest or the smartest. However, when I link to it in the Href, it ignores all spaces, meaning that if a user uploads a document with a space in the name, It doesn't search properly. How would I modify my code to replace any Spaces with % instead when searching?

Here is my code;
The link clicked to download the file;

```
  <a href=@ViewBag.LinkToDownload@item.DocumentId@item.RevisionId@item.Attachment>Download</a>
```

The controller

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Download(string id)
    {
        string path = @"https://filestorageideagen.blob.core.windows.net/documentuploader/";

        return View(path + id);
    }
```

Comment: HttpUtility.UrlEncode may be?

Comment: Check out Html.Encode and Html.Raw. We use a combination of these two to accomplish similar tasks as yours. SO made me remove the @ symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, I have tested this issue. Here are the details, you could refer to them:

Test image: `https://brucechen.blob.core.windows.net/images/hello world.jpg`

**[HttpUtility.UrlEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode(v=vs.110).aspx) or [UrlHelper.Encode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.encode(v=vs.118).aspx)**

This method would encode space to plus (+), when encoding your blob (file) name, you could get `https://brucechen.blob.core.windows.net/images/hello+world.jpg`, but at this point, the file could not be accessed via your browser.

**[Uri.EscapeUriString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapeuristring(v=vs.110).aspx)**

This is an equivalent to JavaScript's `encodeURIComponent()` which could encode space to `%20`, when using this method you could get `https://brucechen.blob.core.windows.net/images/hello%20world.jpg`.

Based on your scenario, you could leverage [Uri.EscapeUriString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapeuristring(v=vs.110).aspx) to encode your url string. Additionally, `%20` is used before the `?` while `+` after, for more details, you could refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211229/in-a-url-should-spaces-be-encoded-using-20-or).