# Safe to have space in hash/URL fragment?

Tags: javascript, html, url, fragment-identifier, hashbang

I'm writing a Javascript driven one-page application where the URL contains a # param eg. (`example.com/#foo/bar`) to represent application state (I've considered using various JS frameworks but cannot, due to various reasons).

Sometimes, the hash may have a space (or many spaces) in it. Eg. `example.com/#foo/bar  bar2`.

1. Is this safe?
2. Are there any other characters that shouldn't be used in the hash portion?

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497908/are-urls-allowed-to-have-a-space-in-them) addresses the question of spaces in the URL portion and recommends escaping spaces. But since changing the fragment after the # doesn't result in a new HTTP request, do those rules apply?

Comment: Fair point. Apart from SEO, does it matter if there's no exclamation point after the #, for what I'm asking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to sidestep the question of what is *safe* and simply state that whitespace in the URL is *illegal* per section 2.4.3 of [RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt). Doing illegal things means that you cannot really predict what software will do when it encounters such a URI.

Besides, if JavaScript is involved you probably don't want to guarantee that changing that hash of a URL doesn't trigger an XHR and cause network activity that re-parses the URL. (For example, you may decide you want to mess with history state or do some analytical tracking `onhashchange`.)

Comment: So for the purposes of RFC 2396 even the fragment-identifier is considered part of the URI?

Comment: @Jayraj yes, see section 4 of the same spec.

Comment: @kojiro section 4.1 actually states `As such, it is not part of a URI` but adds `character restrictions described in Section 2 for URI also apply to the fragment`.