# asp.net mvc querystring paramater add some character that prevent the functionality from working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, parameter-passing, query-string

i work in simple demo to make asearch in asp.net mvc
everything work normal except that the url including + character that prevent the function to be worked

the url looks like this 
http://localhost:3189/products/Index?term=+a&name=Search

when i edit it manually ,it works fine
http://localhost:3189/products/Index?term=a&name=Search

this is my model

```
public class product
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string productName { get; set; }
    public string productModel { get; set; }
    public int productPrice { get; set; }
    public int ModelNum { get; set; }
}
```

and i just used scaffolding to generate controller with views

after that this is my edits on controller

```
public ActionResult Index(string term)
{
    List<product> products = (from pr in db.products
                              where pr.productName.Contains(term) || pr.productName == null
                              select pr).ToList();

    if (products.Count <= 0 || products == null)
    {
        //select all
        return View(db.products);
    }
    //result of search
    return View(products);
}
```

this is my view code in index view

```
<form>
    <input type="search" name="term" value=" " id="term" placeholder="enter your products"/>
    <input type="submit" name="name" value="Search" />
</form>
```

and i really didn't know why this behaviours happens and from where the + signs added as when i remove it manually everthing work noramally 
the url looks like this 
http://localhost:3189/products/Index?term=+a&name=Search

when i edit it manually ,it works fine
http://localhost:3189/products/Index?term=a&name=Search

this is not adublicte i pass only one value to url and the another question for passing multible values

Comment: Where in your code it's the search url being created?

Comment: this is my view code in index view 

    <form>
        <input type="search" name="term" value=" " id="term" placeholder="enter your products"/>
        <input type="submit" name="name" value="Search" />
    
    </form>
i added to topic too ,thanks

Comment: What happens if you change the search field to a text field?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Html Form Submit appends + (plus) in URL params](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417976/html-form-submit-appends-plus-in-url-params). That provides a pretty exhaustive discussion of the issue.

Comment: <input type="text" name="term" value=" " id="term" placeholder="enter your products"/>
it had the same behaviour @RobertMoskal

Comment: this is not adublicte i pass only one value to url and the another question for passing multible values
and the plus added before value it distruct it too @RobertMoskal

Comment: You must have an extra leading space in your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @RobertMoskal explain in comments that the problem because of extra leading space in your input
so i removed  the value attribute as he added the extra term

```
<input type="search" name="term" value=" " id="term" placeholder="enter your products"/>
```

and works fine