# Internet Explorer URL with Just Numeric Characters

Tags: internet-explorer, character, numeric

We want to publish a web site with URL numeric characters. The URL is like http:// 444. When we wrote the URL and hit, we get an error page. The URL returns to http:// 0.0.1.188

When I try it in Firefox there is no problem. What might the problem be?

Comment: check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497908/are-urls-allowed-to-have-a-space-in-them , is there a space before `444`? if it there how about encode it?

Answer (score 1):

That is because x.x.x.x is seen as an IP-v4 address and 444 is out of the range (of its 8 bit tokens)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. As I see, that is the design of IE. Mozilla understands the URL. So I won't be able to use numeric URL using IE. Right?

Comment: probably not if they look like IP addresses.