# URL returned non 200 response code

Tags: solr

I am Indexing Documents by using **SolrPhpClient library**. while making POST request by Solr using extract function reply with

`URL http://localhost/moodledemo/pluginfile.php/99/course/overviewfiles/pre bio-   data.docx` **returned non 200 response code**".

It happens only if the file name include space. if the filename don't have any space it goes well.

I don't conclude why it returns non 200 response with files that have space in their names. while accessing the same path works in browser.

Comment: could it be that the server is doing a redirect to a url with the space correctly encoded and hence returning a 301/302 response code ? (see  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497908/are-urls-allowed-to-have-a-space-in-them )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using rawurlencode() Solved the Issue..

may be the jetty server was responding with non 200 response code with the filename:-

```
How are you.doc
```

Using rawurlencode()

```
How%20are%20you.doc
```

Thanks :)