# CSS Background image error?

Tags: html, css, image, background

I am trying to add a background image to my HTML website, but the syntax I am using doesn't work, and isn't displaying the image at all:

```
background-image:url('My Designs/down-arrows.png');
```

Anyone know if there is an error in this? or is there an equivalent I can use for HTML?

Many thanks, Adam

Comment: Can u show how the class is defined and how the style is applied to the page? Also, are you sure image exits at that path?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the error is that you can't have a space character in the URL:

```
background-image:url('My Designs/down-arrows.png');
```

You *could* use %20?:

```
background-image:url('My%20?Designs/down-arrows.png');
```

But better to change your folder to not use the space at all.

Comment: Tried adding in %20 and still didn't work, ill try remove the space from the file name, Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't work in all browsers. [Read this answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/497972/2997710)