# Add spacing in string on click on anchor tag and displaying in next page url with spacing

Tags: php, html

I have an anchor tag like as follows.

```
<a href="nextpage.php?name=Nike Baby Shoes">shoes</a>
```

What I want is, when I click on this link, it should go to next page and url should become like,

```
nextpage.php?name=Nike-Baby-Shoes
```

But I am not aware about how to put spacing in string while displaying in the url. Right now the url is coming like `nextpage.php?name=Nike%20Baby%20Shoes`.

Please guide me to do that.

Comment: Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497908/are-urls-allowed-to-have-a-space-in-them

Comment: While it would be possible to change the string on click, it is a bad idea. You are adding the variable to the "name" at some stage. This is where you should be removing/replacing all the spaces.

Comment: What's wrong with `nextpage.php?name=Nike%20Baby%20Shoes`?  If you check the `$_GET['name']` value in your `nextpage.php` script, it will just show up as "Nike Baby Shoes".  Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Or do you just want the url to look cleaner?

Comment: in the url,its coming with %20,i want to replace %20 with space from there.

Comment: @user3615820 `%20` is the URL encoding of a space

Comment: Try doing this in your `nextpage.php` script:  `echo $_GET['name'];` and see what comes up

Comment: +1,Look url cleaner, can we replace %20 with -

Comment: @CullyLarson- Ya,i want the url to look cleaner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to just replace the spaces using PHP, when you output the link.  For example:

```
$name = "Nike Baby Shoes";  // or use whatever variable you get the name from

$replaced = urlencode( str_replace(' ', '-', $name) );

echo "<a href='nextpage.php?name={$replaced}'>shoes</a>";
```