# How to cancel automated encoding for img.src?

Tags: html, image, urlencode, url-encoding

The 'src' property of an image is encoded when assigned. Is it possible to avoid it?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/GqQKv/

```
var img = new Image();
img.src ='http://example.com/whatever?s=Hampshire 123&co=USA'
console.log('src', img.src); // instead of spaces we have %20
```

ThanksALot();

Comment: You know you can always decode it again?

Comment: *All* URLs are "encoded" this way. [The character "space" (U+0020) is not valid in an URL.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497908/are-urls-allowed-to-have-a-space-in-them)

Comment: Thanks Jongware, this is the answer I needed.

Comment: I know that I can decode it after, but I wanted to know if it is possible to set 'src' parameter in a decoded way, because one of our services expects requests with clean text.

Answer (score 2):

Just decode it using `decodeURI(uri)`.

That would be `console.log('src', decodeURI(img.src));`.

Updated [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GqQKv/1/)

Comment: Sorry, but it was not the question I asked.

Comment: Nobody forces you to accept an answer. I understand you did not ask this, I just provided an answer, without knowing what uses you have for this code. I just assumed you wanted to print the image's `src`, because that's what this code snippet does.

Comment: PsioniaX, I'm sorry, I didn't mean to be rude. I just wanted to explain why I haven't accepted the answer. I was interested if I could _avoid_ automatic encoding of the src parameter. Probably should made myself more clear.

Comment: I didn't say you were rude, but yes, you could've made yourself more clear.