# scrollTo.js not working with Firefox with spaces in anchor

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, scrollto

I am using this:
https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo

And every browser works but Firefox, specifically when my anchors contain spaces in them. 
I found many threads about it not working in Firefox in general, but not specifically when it is about white spaces.

Comment: [Why would your anchor contain space in the first place](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497908/are-urls-allowed-to-have-a-space-in-them)?

Comment: Any attribute containing spaces is pretty much a bad idea when it comes to HTML, with the exception of classes where whitespace denotes separate class names.  If you REALLY want spaces in the anchors, I suggest you modify the URL with `%20` as the space character inside `scrollTo()`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Attribute Contains Prefix Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-prefix-selector/) like this:

```
$(window).scrollTo($("[id|='y o u r I D']"))
```