# Why Url encoding fails in yahoo OAuth 2.0 in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, oauth

I am implementing Yahoo OAuth 2.0 in C# and ASP.NET, what i have noticed that HttpUtility.UrlEncode(string) fails for the encoding of returnUrl. This is the case when the returnUrl has space in it. 
My code is -

```
    string consumerKey = "xxxxxxx";
    string returnUrl = "http://www.example.com/TutorialCode/Yahoo OAuth 2.0/yahoooauth2.aspx";
    /*Sending User To Authorize Access Page*/
    string url = "https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/request_auth?client_id=" + consumerKey + "&redirect_uri=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(returnUrl) + "&response_type=code&language=en-us";
    Response.Redirect(url);
```

however if i change the returnUrl to-

```
string returnUrl = "http://www.example.com/TutorialCode/YahooOAuth2.0/yahoooauth2.aspx";
```

then it works. 
Why it is a problem in URL Encoding ? can somebody shed some light in this.

Regards

Comment: me too ran into this issue, not sure why yahoo has such a weird strategy

Comment: @saravanan did you got the solution as to how to encode the url which has spaces in C#??

Comment: Nope, did you try using a + instead of the space

Comment: yes i tried + and also %20 but everything seemed to fail.

Comment: they did not have a proper documentation in regards to these. very disappointing. can't you have the url tweaked to not have spaces in it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the URL encoding, but apparently that Yahoo refuses Redirect URI's with spaces (even if correctly URL-encoded). However, your URLs should not contain spaces in the first place as they are unsafe characters and must be URL encoded, see: [Is a URL allowed to contain a space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497908/is-a-url-allowed-to-contain-a-space). Note that in that case the `redirect_uri` value would become double URL encoded.

Comment: This answer is a bit confusing. You say that spaces should be url encoded, but the OP **is** url encoding the url.  Do you mean the space character should be encoded first to %20, and then the whole thing urlencoded because it is being put inside of another url?  If so, what utility methods should be used to accomplish the first part?

Comment: I meant to say that the the original value of `returnUrl` must not contain spaces.

Comment: i have tried putting %20 for spaces but it did not worked. Yahoo documents does not say anything about url encoding the returnUrl.