# Preserve white space in URL with PHP

Tags: php

I am stuck big time on this problem and google has been of no help to me so far. I am trying to find a way to preserve white space in a URL with moderate to no luck.

I have a form that needs to gather post data, mail it, and then append the post data to the URL as comma separated value and redirects them to a page where they download a product.

Once the user presses download that page reads the data in the URL and applies it to a billing invoice (the program is billed on time usage).

A simplified example:

```
$addressOne = $_POST['addressOne'];
$newURL = "http://subdomain.domain.com/connectnow=on?" . ", Address1=" . $addressOne;
If(mailSent) {
    header("Location: $newURL")
}
```

There are a lot more values obviously, but the address is one of the areas that I am having this issue.

I have tried doing something like:

```
$newURL = str_replace("  ", "&nbsp;", $newURL);
```

That worked as far as preserving the whitespace in the URL visually, but when the program that gets downloaded reads the URL it replaces the   as %C2%.

I have also tried:

```
$newURL = str_replace("  ", " \40", $newURL);
```

That made the spaces in the URL convert back to %20.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `urlencode()` and `urldecode()`?

Comment: better you should use `urlencode` and `decode`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497908/is-a-url-allowed-to-contain-a-space

Comment: Space and special characters are URL encoded while in browser if you read url in the redirected page using PHP you will get space back. It is normal behavior.

Comment: The reason you can't have literal whitespace in the path is that a HTTP request line has to be serialized as `GET␣/virt/path?params␣HTTP/1.1`. Extra spaces there would invalidate it. Which is why browsers substitute `+` or `%20` right away. -- Also please don't copy sample code from Word etc. Those typographic quotes make poor examples for any other users that accidentally come across this question.

Comment: I have tried using both urlencode($newURL) and urldecode($newURL), Sorry I should have stated that earlier.

Answer (score 2):

URL:

> www.site.com/my spaces preserved/

[urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

```
www.site.com%2Fmy+spaces+preserved%2F
```

[urldecode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

```
www.site.com/my spaces preserved/
```

Comment: I tried urlencode() previously and didn't mention it. I just tried the urldecode() and it didn't work either. I know that it is possible because this is a redesign of a site that was originally done (by someone else) five years ago using coldfusion.

Comment: what did you got (output) when trying the urldecode()?

Comment: www.site.com/my%20space%20preserved/