# Mailto link is not working in chrome and firefox browsers.But same thing working in My android phone

Tags: mailto

**mailto for email**

I wrote below code in my blog,

```html
<a href="mailto:harehare@gmail.com?subject=My blog">
<div class='social-popout'><img alt='Gmail social icon' src='http://i57assa.com/106asaj5h.jpg'/></div>
</a>
```

I also chnage setting in my chrome browser's handler too...

Comment: Works for me in Chrome on OSX, to the point that it brings up the configuration dialog for Mail.app.

Answer (score 2):

Your mailto-URl contains a space. Spaces in URLs are unsafe characters and must be encoded. See [Is a URL allowed to contain a space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497908/is-a-url-allowed-to-contain-a-space)