# W3C Markup Validation - Illegal character in path segment: not a URL code point

Tags: html, url, w3c-validation

I have a problem with the following string:

```
<a href="../Uses In Industry/planes.html">
```

And it gives the following error:

> Bad value `../Uses In Industry/planes.html` for attribute `href` on element `a`: Illegal character in path segment: not a URL code point.

I have the same issue with a few more lines, and I can't see what the problem is.

Comment: The spaces are. You need to properly URL-encode them. (And if you don’t know what that is/means, please research it.)

Comment: Btw., I don’t know what validation mode/HTML doctype you used – but for HTML5 validation (https://validator.w3.org/nu/), the validator even outputs a message specifically saying how spaces should be encoded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @CBroe mentioned in the comments, spaces are illegal characters in a URL and must be "escaped". The way to do this is encode them as %20 or, better yet, eliminate them all together by using hyphens or no space at all.

[More information can be found in this SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497908/is-a-url-allowed-to-contain-a-space)