# How to make retrofit get request with strings?

Tags: java, retrofit

I need to make a `Get` request in retrofit and the parameter would be `Strings` separated by space.

For example:

```
http://www.something.com?req=hello testing
```

When we hit the above URL in browser it will become like this:

```
http://www.something.com/?req=hello%20testing
```

How can I achieve with retrofit? I know the basic and able to call the `Get` request from retrofit successfully but all of those contain one string or similar parameters.

```
 @GET("/search?req={req}")
public Observable<List<Model>> getWarehouse (String req);
```

To call above request I wrote following code:

```
adapter.create(WarehouseAPI.class).getWarehouse()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<List<Warehouse>>(){
    ..........
    ..........
```

What do I need to change for passing string with spaces in above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used **retrofit** . It's not a retrofit issue. Since it's a **GET** request, a URL must not contain a space, it must be encoded either using **+** or **%20**. Which is again decoded on the server side.

Have a look here http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt

For more info

[Is a URL allowed to contain a space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497908/is-a-url-allowed-to-contain-a-space)