# PHP does not copy the file properly

Tags: php, image, file, copy

im copying a file from another domain. It does not give me any errors but the files does not get recognized and its different size from the original file. Its the same extension i checked. so im kinda clueless.

```
if (!copy('http://maholi.com/image/data/Products/Linen - Juvenile and Infant/1440.jpg', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/resources/categories/tttt6.jpg')) {
echo "failed";
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: Most likely you did not really copy the file but receive some html error message or similar form the remote system. PHP cannot known what you expect inside the file, so it stored whatever it receives. I suggest you simply take a look into the file to see what it contains.

Comment: Did you try opening it in a text editor? Some sites might serve html instead of the image if they don't like your referer.

Comment: ^^ make sure you use a text editor to open the file

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: How about removing spaces from src file "`http://maholi.com/image/data/Products/Linen%20-%20Juvenile%20and%20Infant/1440.jpg`" and make sure the dest path exists.

Comment: yes you guys are right. i opened with text editor and it shows a full html page for some reason.ill try encoding the src now

Comment: yes i updated the spacing and it did the job! thank you!

Comment: is there a php function that would do this for me? cause i got an array of those src's

Comment: of course you have permission to use those images ;) ..`urlencode()`

Comment: i tried that and it gives out an error since it converts the whole string , not just spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```
if (!copy('http://maholi.com/image/data/Products/Linen%20-%20Juvenile%20and%20Infant/1440.jpg', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/tttt6.jpg')) {
  echo "failed";
}
```

**Edit:** URL's are not allowed to contain spaces. See "[Is a URL allowed to contain a space?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/497972/4405465)". Your web browser will automatically encode illegal characters, making you believe they are allowed.