# .NET Uri.ToString() ruins the URL?

Tags: c#, .net, url, uri

I've noticed that if you call `Uri.ToString()` when URI behind is URL with percent encoded spaces (%20), then you will have malformed URL as the result:

```
// result: "http://example.com/test segment"
new Uri("http://example.com/test%20segment").ToString();
```

Since [URL is URI](https://danielmiessler.com/study/url-uri/#gs.s5iM2MM) (opposite statement is not correct) and URL with non encoded spaces [is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497908/is-a-url-allowed-to-contain-a-space) it looks like it's not safe to use Uri as the container for URL.

Is it correct behaviour?

Comment: Presumably `ToString()` is parsing the `%20` following the parent encoding spec, and determines that it should be a space.

Comment: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) says it should return the string with regular spaces. Use .OriginalString if you want the `%20` instead of spaces.

Comment: The documentation you pointed out says `.ToString()` returns spaces while `.OriginalString` returns `%20`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
// result: "http://example.com/test segment"
new Uri("http://example.com/test%20segment").ToString();

// result: "http://example.com/test%20segment"
new Uri("http://example.com/test%20segment").OriginalString;
```