# JSoup connect to URL with whitespaces

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to use JSoup in Java to obtain information in html. In my application the user can enter a keyword which is then processed on a seperate website and I obtain then the results.

If the keyword is: "this is a test" this should translate into "www.mywebsite.org/q=this is a test".
When I process this in JSoup, it connects to the website "www.mywebsite.org/q=this%2520is%2520a%2520test" which is incorrect. I already tried replace the spaces with "%20" but the adding of "%25" still occurs. How can I fix this?

Comment: [Other similar questions](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+jsoup+url+with+spaces)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497908/is-a-url-allowed-to-contain-a-space

Comment: thanks everybody! Due to your links I found out that I can replace the space by "+"