# How to send photo, audio in telegram bot from URL with space

Tags: telegram-bot

When i send photo or audio from URL work fine but if URL have space photo don't send

how to send photo, audio in telegram bot from URL with space?

I test '%20' '+' but don't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is a URL allowed to contain a space?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497908/is-a-url-allowed-to-contain-a-space)

Comment: Can you post your url with problem?

Comment: @DanilPyatnitsev no i can't send

Comment: @ARASHz4 I think what DanilPyatnitsev was trying to ask was: can include an example URL in the question?

Comment: @DanilPyatnitsev like this url : http://dl3.farskidsiha.com/P1/1395/11/19/Xaniar%20-%20Age%20Mimoondi.mp3