# Audio Player Files not loading online but works locally

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Hi ive done a project for university of creating a web application. I added in an audioplayer, and it worked perfectly fine locally, but when I added it to my web app online i get the error:

```
GET https://mitul106.000webhostapp.com/app5/public_html/app5/components/G-Eazy%…20Kehlani%20-%20Good%20Life.mp3/G-Eazy%20&%20Kehlani%20-%20Good%20Life.mp3 404 () 
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.  music:1
```

The directory path is correct im not too sure what else the issue could be. If you need any more of me feel free to ask and thankyou in advance! :)

Comment: add code here or a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Are the other hosted pages/files accessible online?

Comment: @Mitul Suchak I think it has file name or path issue, because file name has containing blank space and adding the `%20-%20` try with the correct file name.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ae52cugk/

Comment: Ive changed the path, removed all spaces, and at the moment am only working with one song to see if i can get it to work all other pages are accessible online yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per standards, [src](https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html_images.asp) attribute should contain a [valid URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Syntax). Since s[pace characters are not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497908/is-a-url-allowed-to-contain-a-space) in URLs, you have to [encode](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_urlencode.asp) them.

You can write:

```
src="Sound%20Awesome.mp3"
```

**but NOT**

```
src="My-Sound%20Awesome.mp3"
```

Check your Sound File name - It has "-" in it.

Path to the audio file is not correct in your case. Try changing it to:

```
https://mitul106.000webhostapp.com/GoodLife.mp3
```

Comment: Do you have an online URL where I can check it?

Comment: Ok, so there is an issue with accessing the mp3 file. When I open https://mitul106.000webhostapp.com/public_html/app5/components/GoodLife.mp3 it gives 404 error. So, please check the folder and path where you have all mp3 files.

Comment: but the path is correct, and all the other files in there load so where would my issue lie?

Comment: @MitulSuchak Try changing your path to: https://mitul106.000webhostapp.com/GoodLife.mp3 because I can see all files in main directory if I look at this URL: https://mitul106.000webhostapp.com/

Comment: Oh myyy, sorry for wasting your time on something so simple, I was being stupid aha. Thankyou so much works!

Comment: @Mitul would you mind clicking up arrow to appreciate my time? ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove all spaces from the file names and replace then with underscores (_) for working with them on the web.

So if your mp3 file is Teri Meri Kahani.mp3 rename it to teri_meri_kahani.mp3 .

Also remove spaces from all the directories if any in which you store songs online.

Comment: removed all spaces and any online directories have an underscore, still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Spaces are not supported in file/directory names when using them in websites.

So just remove the spaces or replace them by a underscore(_)

I hope I can help:)

Comment: removing spaces didnt help