# Spring RestTemplate getForObject getting 404

Tags: java, spring, rest, http

I'm trying to make a get request to an Api Rest but I'm always getting 404, nevertheless if try copying  queryUrl  in a browser or postMan it works perfectly.

```
restTemplate.getForObject(queryUrl, entity ,Integer.class);
```

I've also tried this:

```
HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(httpHeaders);
log.debug("request headers: " + entity.getHeaders());
ResponseEntity response = restTemplate.exchange(queryUrl, 
HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
```

But nothing changes. 
Can anyone help me?

Comment: try with postman or ARC first against the endpoint and then check with the code

Comment: As I said in the previous post in Postman works perfectly that's the weird for me. Thanks for your response

Comment: Without much information we can&amp;#39;t do anything .. your usage is right. Might be u can share some url just to ensure everything is right or share the working postman one sample screenshot would do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were right Barath the usage is correct. The problem was that UriComponentBuilder was including a blank space at the en of the URL.

I've fixed it with a trim.

```
String queryUrl = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(HOST)
                .path(PATH)
                .buildAndExpand(param)
                .toUriString().trim();
```

Answer (score 5):

This took me a bit to figure out, so I'll leave a little note here hoping one day it helps someone.
I kept getting a 404 when making a get request with ResTemplate.getForEntity(URL, Type).  The URL worked in Chrome, Postman, but not in my code.
It ended up being because I had an [unsafe character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/497972/691928) in my URL, an % to be exact, because my URL had spaces and so instead of space the URL had %20.  Postman and Chrome could handle this, but not my code.  Once I replaced the unsafe character with an actual space all was well.

Hope it works out for you too.

Answer (score 0):

When your url contains "%", then you shoud use restTemplate.getForObject(new URI(url),xx.class), it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue for me the issue was not the encoded path but another application (nodeJS) was running on the same port.