# htaccess clean urls issue, its not redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm strugling to make this work. At the moment my `.htaccess` contains the following code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
  # Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

  # Turn on the engine:
  RewriteEngine on

  #RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ product.php?pid=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
  RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ product.php?pid=$1&pname=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
</IfModule>
```

My Original URL is something linke this

```
product.php?pid=1&pname=this is a product name
```

My clean URL should be something like below:

```
example.com/1/this is a product name
```

This is how my `<a>` tag generate by PHP:

```
$url = "{$pid}/{$pname}";
$url = html_escape($url, 'UTF-8'); 
echo "<a href='$url'>Link</a>";
```

Above first rule is working for me. But when I try it with `pname` variable like I have done in second rule is not working for me.

can anybody tell me what is wrong with this?

Comment: Are there spaces in your product names? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497908/is-a-url-allowed-to-contain-a-space

Comment: You cannot have white space characters in a URL.

Comment: What's `html_escape`?

Comment: You want to `url_encode()` your URLs.

Comment: @arkascha Can you show me an example? I tried it like this `$url = url_encode($pid)."/".url_encode($pname);`. But its not working

Comment: And "But its not working" means what? What _are_ the URLs you use, _exactly_. And what _is_ the issue you have, _exactly_ .

Comment: My `<a>` tag is something like this : `$url = url_encode($pid)."/".url_encode($pname); echo <a href='{$url}'>link</a>;`

Comment: I asked for _exact_ statements for a reasons. "Something like" does not help, be specific. So what values can such a `$pid` and a `$pname` take? The issue most likely is that `\w` does not match every character you are using there...

Comment: Its going to `404 Not Found` page. Then my URL is something like this : `mydomain.com/1/Ketasa bsraysas luytasas biuiyas miuytrasas`

Comment: can anybody look at this problem? thank you