# Codeigniter - 404 page not found on folder name change

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am running codeigniter 3.1 in my localhost.

When I access my "Codeigniter" folder from localhost, it opens fine.

But when I change the folder name to "myProject",
and try to access `localhost/myProject` or `localhost/myProject/index.php` it is showing "404 Page Not Found".

But when I tried to access `localhost/myProject/index.php/Welcome` it worked!

Comment: 1. If you change the folder name back to "Codeigniter", everything is ok, isn't it?

2. Do you use .htaccess?

Comment: yes, when again i am renaming it to codeigniter it is working. I am using .htaccess with trying $config['index_page'] = ''; $config['base_url'] = ''; (in config.php)

Comment: Ok i got the actual problem.

Comment: When i am giving a space in project name like "my Project" it providing error, but "myProject" does not providing any error. Anyone know why?

Comment: Hope it help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497908/is-a-url-allowed-to-contain-a-space

Comment: @VikashSDNT Because leaving spaces in path names is for Windows dummies. Don't leave spaces for paths that are supposed to be referenced in a url, unless it's in a query string.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your codeigniter project

1. open **myProject**
2. open **application**
3. open **config** then open `config.php` file.
4. change your `$config['base_url']` to `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/myProject/';`

you need to set **the base_url** on your project folder name.

Answer (score 0):

You can make dynamic base url also, once its done, then you will no need to chnage base url in config.php, even if you will upload your project on server, then will no need to change base url in config.php.

**Please use this code, to make dynamic base url.**

```
$root = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https://" : "http://").$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root.= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url'] = $root;
```

Thanks