# Keep Spaces Intact In Http Springboot URL

Tags: spring-boot, solr, solrj, solrcloud, solr4

I am trying to fetch some string consisting spaces in it from Solr from Spring Boot but the spring boot is replacing space with `+` in the internal HTTP request as in the example below `/Tag-+1/` instead of `/Tag- 1/`. 
ex:

> q=tags:/Tag-+1/

While if I execute same query `q=tags:/Tag- 1/` in solr admin UI(Web Client) it is working. the datatype used is "string". I want to know if spaces can be kept intact in the Spring Boot HTTP request or is there any other solution.

Comment: A space isn't valid in a URL, it *should* be replaced with a `+` (or URL-escaped to `%20`). See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/497908/3001761

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but then how can i resolve my issue?