# preg_replace all "_" by spaces only in url

Tags: php, regex, url, preg-replace

I have an html file containing some data, including some urls.

Only on theses urls, I want to replace the `_` character by a space (via a php file).

So an url like this:

```
</p><p><a rel="nofollow" class="external text" href="http://10.20.0.30:1234/index.php/this_is_an_example.html">How_to_sample.</a>
```

will become

```
</p><p><a rel="nofollow" class="external text" href="http://10.20.0.30:1234/index.php/this is an example.html">How_to_sample.</a>
```

This has not to affect the `_` that are not on urls.

I think this might be possible with a preg_replace, but i don't know how to proceed for this.

The following code in incorrect as it replace every `_` and not just the one in url.

```
$content2 = preg_replace('/[_]/', ' ', $content);
```

Thanks.

EDIT:

Thanks for `preg_replace_callback` suggestion, this is what I was looking for.

```
    // search pattern
    $pattern = '/href="http:\/\/10.20.0.30:1234\/index.php\/(.*?).html">/s';

    // the function call
    $content2 = preg_replace_callback($pattern, 'callback', $content);

    // the callback function
    function callback ($m) {
        print_r($m);
        $url = str_replace("_", " ", $m[1]);
        return 'href="http://10.20.0.30:1234/index.php/'.$url.'.html">';
    }
```

Comment: Use a `preg_replace_callback` to match the urls, then in the callback replace the `_`s with `str_replace` (don't use regexes for static strings...) and you're good.

Comment: I don't see any unqualified underscores in your sample data.   I mean, it looks like you are safe to replace all underscores.   Please update your input to be my representative of your situation.

Comment: The preg_replace_callback was what i'm looking for ! Thanks.

Comment: Answers should not be posted as edits on the question. This is not how Q & A works.

Comment: Yes you're right, but i'm not able to post an answer properly. I have a alert message saying that i don't have permission.

Comment: "We are no longer accepting answers from this account."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Older and wiser: Don't use regex - it is not necessary and it may be prone to instability because regex is not DOM-aware.  Use an HTML parser to isolate the `<a>` tags and then the `href` attribute, then make a simple `str_replace()` call.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/o6aUs))

```
$html = <<<HTML
<p><a rel="nofollow" class="external text" href="http://10.20.0.30:1234/index.php/this_is_an_example.html">How_to_sample.</a></p>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument; 
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $a) {
    $a->setAttribute('href', str_replace('_', '%20', $a->getAttribute('href')));
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Output:

```
<p><a rel="nofollow" class="external text" href="http://10.20.0.30:1234/index.php/this%20is%20an%20example.html">How_to_sample.</a></p>
```

A url should not contain any spaces, spaces should be encoded as `%20`. - [Is a URL allowed to contain a space?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/497908/2943403)

---

Original answer:

If you are open to some regex trickery, you can accomplish your task with `preg_replace()` alone.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/BXEgW))

```
$input = '</p><p><a rel="nofollow" class="external text" href="http://10.20.0.30:1234/index.php/this_is_an_example.html">How_to_sample.</a>';

$pattern = '~(?:\G|\Qhttp://10.20.0.30:1234/index.php\E[^_]+)\K_([^_.]*)~';

echo preg_replace($pattern, " $1", $input);
```

Output:

```
</p><p><a rel="nofollow" class="external text" href="http://10.20.0.30:1234/index.php/this is an example.html">How_to_sample.</a>
```

`\G` is the "continue" metacharacter.  It allows you to make multiple consecutive matches after the expected porrion of the url.

`\Q..\E` says "treat all characters between the two points literally-- so no escaping is necessary.

`\K` means "restart the fullstring match from this point".

[Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PorzXY/2)

Since you are building a url, I reckon you should be replacing with `%20`.

I suppose my pattern should deny the start of the string after `\G` for best practices...

```
$pattern = '~(?:\G(?!^)|\Qhttp://10.20.0.30:1234/index.php\E[^_]+)\K_([^_.]*)~';
```