# Non-escaped query parameters for URL

Tags: go, url-parameters

I want to create a query parameter without escaping the query string.

For example, I need to create a query parameter `q` with the content

```
"before:{2019-12-24 19:57:34}"
```

so that the URL is

```
https://android-review.googlesource.com/changes/?q=before:{2019-12-24 19:57:34}
```

If I use this code ([Golang Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/M5ZmLFlVE2U))

```
url, _ := url.Parse("https://android-review.googlesource.com/changes/")
q := url.Query()
q.Set("q", "before:{2019-12-24 19:57:34}")
url.RawQuery = q.Encode()
fmt.Println(url)
```

`url` is escaping the special characters, spaces, and brackets:

```
https://android-review.googlesource.com/changes/?q=before%3A%7B2019-12-24+19%3A57%3A34%7D
```

How can I solve this issue except manually creating the URL (without query parameters then)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want your URL query to be encoded, then don't use the `Encode()` method. Instead, set the `RawQuery` value directly, yourself:

```golang
url, _ := url.Parse("https://android-review.googlesource.com/changes/")
url.RawQuery = "q=before:{2019-12-24 19:57:34}"
fmt.Println(url)
```

Output:

```
https://android-review.googlesource.com/changes/?q=before:{2019-12-24 19:57:34}
```

[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/1nHJzcFsP2c)

Keep in mind, however, that this is a recipe for potential disaster, depending on how that url is eventually used. In particular, the space in that URL should be escaped, according to RFC. See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/497908/13860).

Perhaps you'll want to implement your own minimal escaping, if that's compatible with your use-case.